# how to get first element in angular 5 using ngFor directive?

Tags: angular, angular5

ngFor directive worked fine when I used to show all the colors from an array of colors but when I tried to check whether it is first element of the array or not then it shows an error "can't bind to ngForFirst since it is not .... blah blah blah ". It shows almost a page full of error. I'm very new to angular and the tutorial I'm going through the tutor doesn't get any error. Don't know why. Help me

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
     selector: 'app-test',
     template: `
       <div *ngFor = "let color of colors; first as i">
           <h3> {{i}}  </h3>
       </div>` ,
     styles: []
    })

    export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
      public name = "Dipesh";
      public colors = ["Red", "Black", "Green"];
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      }
```

Comment: "can't bind to ngForFirst since it is not .... blah blah blah " -- this helps a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 <div *ngFor = "let color of colors; let first = first; let last = last">
               <h3> {{first}}  </h3>
               <h3> {{last}}  </h3>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access to the first element like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let color of colors; let first = first;"> ...
```

Note:

You have more functionallity available like: **odd**, **even** or **last**

[Official documentation here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Answer (score 0):

with using "as" you try to translate "**first**" into "**i**" type object.
that is why you are getting error.

you can declare variable in angular by using  "let" keyword.
ex : let variableName = index

Comment: Not true, angular.io documentation shows the above approach as well.